# What Design Patterns are present in the .NET Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I was asked the question "What Gang of Four Design Patterns are used in Entity Framework".  I could not really think of any.

Can anyone help to identify some of the GOF design patterns in EF?

Comment: You could say the `ObjectContext` implements both a unit-of-work and a repository. But really, this question as it's worded seems vague & open to interpretation.

Comment: Neither pattern is a GOF patern

Comment: What is the point of this question?

Comment: @Dmitry: Oops, you're completely right. I was rather tired when I wrote that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book) and the GoF-patterns listed there, I came up with this list:

- **Factory Method**, an Entity Framework `ObjectContext` provides a `CreateObjectSet<T>` method, which creates an `ObjectSet<T>` for the given type. Since those object-sets are the main approach to access the entities within a context, I would say it is also a very important pattern used in EF.
- **Proxy**, obviously EF dynamically creates proxy-types for your entities (unless you tell it not to, or it can't create a proxy because a class is sealed or does not qualify as a "proxyable" type).
- **Decorator**, this might be a bit far fetched, but to implement lazy-loading in proxy-types, the property-getters of navigation-properties are overloaded, to perform the lazy-loading until requested. This is handled in the proxy type, but also depends on whether lazy-loading is enabled and the navigation-property itself.
- **Interpreter**, EF introduced Entity-SQL which is a somewhat generalized form of SQL that also has knowledge of the object-orientied entities. You can define a those queries as strings which are then interpreted by EF and turned into provider-dependend SQL.
- **Strategy**, looking at the various overloads of the `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` method, you can select from different strategies that are used to determine changes made on known entities.
- **Memento**, the `ObjectStateManager` keeps track of changes made to the entities and can be used to access those information including the original-values.
- **Facade**, exposing entity-sets as IQueryable should qualify as "a simplified interface to a large body of code", since turning such expressions into Entity SQL and than provider-specific SQL is a big deal.
- **Observer**, `ObjectContext` provides two eventy `ObjectMaterialized` and `SavingChanges`. Since .NET events are an implementation of the observer-pattern, EF also qualifies for this one.

I may have been very generous with naming patterns here, but with some digging you can find a lot of places where EF actually implements those patterns. But since the book is out for nearly 20 years, you can expect that some of these patterns are considered a standard, which isn't worth mentioning. For example the **Observer** pattern or the **Iterator** pattern (which I haven't mentioned, just because IQueryable implements IEnumerable).